# How to send my public IP (obtained with netcat) to a server in a simple way?

Tags: network-programming, netcat

I learned to get my public ip address using netcat on a very basic box. Server 1.

I want to somehow sent/update it to my server 2 (CentOS 7). The server 2 has a public static ip address as well as a DNS entry for my Domain.

Any ideas how to transfer this little piece of information in a very simple way to server 2? I want to use it in my /etc/hosts file.

The server 2 has already apache, iptables, selinux, dovecot, postfix and some other default software installed.

Comment: Have you tried using ssh? Thats’s close to the most basic way possible.

Comment: Server 1 is very simple. I will take a look. Could you maybe give me an example doing it via ssh?

Comment: Maybe like: echo 'Some Text' | ssh user@remotehost -T "cat > /remotefile.txt"

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
ssh -t username@host 'echo "string" > file'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fortunately ssh is available on server 1. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad that the answer helped.